# c# SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault must be called before the first

Tags: c#

I tried to search for this exception but i couldn't find any solution on my case

I'am using the code Below to invoke a .NET Application :

```
        Assembly assem = Assembly.Load(Data);
        MethodInfo method = assem.EntryPoint;           
        var o = Activator.CreateInstance(method.DeclaringType);            
        method.Invoke(o, null);
```

the Application that will be invoked has a Form and in the EntryPoint of the Application :

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); //Exception
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

`SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault` must be called before the first `IWin32Window` object is created in the application.

EDIT :

```
        Assembly a = Assembly.Load(Data);
        MethodInfo method = a.GetType().GetMethod("Start");
        var o = Activator.CreateInstance(method.DeclaringType);            
        method.Invoke(o, null);
```

Comment: You can't do that.  You could try creating its form manually.

Comment: I didnt get it ? can you explain pls ?

Comment: i had this problem because i had created a static property of type `FrmMain` and then i had the default value set to a new instance of `FrmMain` like `internal static FrmMain MainFormInstance {get; set;} = new FrmMain();`  so when i read the comments and answers i did not get why i'm getting my message until i realized what i did yesterday at the last minute. so basically the form was initialized before the method call because it was static...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should create a new method that skips the initialization and look with reflection for the `Start` method. But the `Application.Start` will block the current thread. If you don't want to start a new message-pump, you should try to lookup the Form class with reflection.

---

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
        var filename = Path.Combine(path, "WindowsFormsApplication1.exe");
        var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(filename);
        var programType = assembly.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == "Program"); // <-- if you don't know the full namespace and when it is unique.
        var method = programType.GetMethod("Start", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
        method.Invoke(null, new object[] { });
    }
}
```

And the loading assembly:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Start();
    }


    public static void Start()   // <-- must be marked public!
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Start");
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

This works here!

Comment: And look with reflection for the Run method ?

Comment: Thats right. The problem is that the visualstyles etc may only be called ones at the start of the application. If you load an assembly (applies also to exefile assemblies) they will be loaded in the same appdomain.

Comment: So i basically need to skip the EntryPoint Main() And Directly create instant of The Run Method ?

Comment: That will do... also you want to keep the main it self if you want to run it from commandline etc.

Comment: will now i get the exception object not set to an instance of an object what's wrong ?

Comment: If it can't find the method, you might mark it public

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Thank You Sooooo Much Sir ! , if i want to Get Byte[] Data and Load it the Same way it works ? Example i have a byte[] Array holds the Data already stored

Comment: Meaning the byte array holds the binary of the to-load assembly? You should try it ;-) I had it working some time ago.

Comment: It works ! , thanks sir , and i have  To use a Form.ShowDialog() Instead of calling the Application.Run() Method